Problem with added dataframe column shift
I tried to apply my newly acquired pandas skills to a typical ANOVA calculation on large dataset with 5, partially nested indices. The corresponding dataframe "dSchema" looks like this:
        X  q  c  s  r  i
1     3.0  0  0  0  0  0
2     3.0  0  0  0  0  1
3     3.0  0  0  0  0  2
4     3.0  0  0  0  0  3
5     3.0  0  0  0  0  4
...   ... .. .. .. .. ..
8496  1.0  8  4  9  1  0
8497  0.0  8  4  9  1  1
8498  0.0  8  4  9  1  2
8499  0.0  8  4  9  1  3
8500  0.0  8  4  9  1  4

[8500 rows x 6 columns]

For the actual calculation I came up with the following column:
               filter
0     ['0', '0', '0']
1     ['0', '0', '1']
2     ['0', '0', '2']
3     ['0', '0', '3']
4     ['0', '0', '4']
...               ...
8495  ['8', '9', '0']
8496  ['8', '9', '1']
8497  ['8', '9', '2']
8498  ['8', '9', '3']
8499  ['8', '9', '4']

[8500 rows x 1 columns]

The one column 'filter' contains strings of lists
But when I tried to add the column 'filter' to the original dataframe, something strange happened:
        X  q  c  s  r  i           filter
1     3.0  0  0  0  0  0  ['0', '0', '1']
2     3.0  0  0  0  0  1  ['0', '0', '2']
3     3.0  0  0  0  0  2  ['0', '0', '3']
4     3.0  0  0  0  0  3  ['0', '0', '4']
5     3.0  0  0  0  0  4  ['0', '0', '0']
...   ... .. .. .. .. ..              ...
8496  1.0  8  4  9  1  0  ['8', '9', '1']
8497  0.0  8  4  9  1  1  ['8', '9', '2']
8498  0.0  8  4  9  1  2  ['8', '9', '3']
8499  0.0  8  4  9  1  3  ['8', '9', '4']
8500  0.0  8  4  9  1  4             <NA>

[8500 rows x 7 columns]

the column 'filter' appears shifted up relative to the original dataframe by one position. I was unable to correct this with the .shift() function, when attaching 'filter' to 'schema'. Can anybody explain this to me, or even better, help me to fix it?

Hi, you have not shared what you tried to do to solve the problem. That's always a first step!

Your indices do not align: first one starts at 0, second at 1. You're not showing how you are adding this column, but that is doubtlessly the issue: your result has the matches on the indices. So, 0 won't be there and 8500 gets filled with NaN, since it's not present in the index for your 'filter' column.

You need to reindex one of your dataframes so that the numeration from each dataframe's index matches. Assuming the dataframe with the values to set for column "filter" is called df_filter you could do the following:
dSchema = dSchema.reset_index(drop=True)
dSchema["filter"] = df_filter["filter"]

Or, if you want to keep the indexes from dSchema unaltered, you could use:
dSchema["filter"] = df_filter["filter"].values


You could just use .reset_index() to discard the calculation index (which is incremented by 1 as noted in the comments)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  # discard 1-based index

However, you may also want to consider if you want to store your filter as strings in lists in a column, which to me feels very inefficient when they could easily be additional, numeric columns
